# Find common (inclusion) ranges in arrays of ranges

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to do it but i am not able put condition. I want to find common slot.

- first person test is available between 10 AM to 12PM
- second person elton is available between 9 AM to 10:30 AM and 10:30
  AM to 11 AM
- third person shawn is available between 10:30 AM to 11:00 AM

Hence common slot will be 10:30 AM to 11:00 AM

```
const input = [
  {
    email: 'test@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '10:00:00', end: '12:00:00' }
    ],
  },
  {
    email: 'elton@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '09:00:00', end: '10:30:00'},
      {start: '10:30:00', end: '11:00:00' }
    ],
  },
  {
    email: 'shawn@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '10:30:00', end: '11:00:00' }
    ],
  },
];
```

output:

```
 [
      {start: '10:30:00', end: '11:00:00' }
  ]
```

second input example

```
const input = [
  {
    email: 'test@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '10:00:00', end: '12:00:00' }
    ],
  },
  {
    email: 'elton@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '09:00:00', end: '10:30:00'},
      {start: '10:30:00', end: '11:00:00' },
      {start: '14:30:00', end: '15:00:00' }
    ],
  }
];
```

output:

```
[
 {start: '10:00:00', end: '11:00:00' }
]
```

third input example:

```
const input = [
  {
    email: 'test@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '10:00:00', end: '12:00:00' },
      {start: '14:30:00', end: '15:00:00' }
    ],
  },
  {
    email: 'elton@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '09:00:00', end: '10:30:00'},
      {start: '10:30:00', end: '11:00:00' },
      {start: '14:30:00', end: '15:00:00' }
    ],
  }
];
```

output :

```
[
 {start: '10:00:00', end: '11:00:00' },
 {start: '14:30:00', end: '15:00:00' }
]
```

Code I have tried so far

```js
function generateIntersectSlot(interviewerRange) {
  if (!interviewerRange.length) {
    return [];
  }
  for (let interviewer of interviewerRange) {
    for (let nextInterviewer of interviewerRange) {
      if (interviewer.email == nextInterviewer.email) {
        continue;
      }
      console.log(interviewer.email, 'interviewerSlot email')
      console.log(nextInterviewer.email, 'nextInterviewer email')
      const interviewerSlot = interviewer.range;
      const nextInterviewerSlot = nextInterviewer.range;
      for (let intSlot of interviewerSlot) {
        for (let nextIntSlot of nextInterviewerSlot) {

          console.log(intSlot, 'intSlot')
          console.log(nextIntSlot, 'nextIntSlot')
          // if(new Date(`${getDate}T${intSlot.start}`) >= new Date(`${getDate}T${nextIntSlot.start}`) ) {
          //   console.log(intSlot, 'asd')
          // } else {

          // } 


        }
      }
    }
  }
}

generateIntersectSlot(input);
```

```html
<script>
  const input = [{
      email: 'test@test.com',
      range: [{
        start: '10:00:00',
        end: '12:00:00'
      }],
    },
    {
      email: 'elton@test.com',
      range: [{
          start: '09:00:00',
          end: '10:30:00'
        },
        {
          start: '10:30:00',
          end: '11:00:00'
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      email: 'shawn@test.com',
      range: [{
        start: '10:30:00',
        end: '11:00:00'
      }],
    },
  ];
</script>
```

Comment: please provide more info for what you want to do exactly

Comment: I edited the main post. I want to find common slot from the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to implement the function to intersect and union ranges and then we will need to loop the persons and ranges, find the intersections and then merge intersections that belong together:

```js
function max(first, second) {
    return (first > second) ? first : second;
}

function min(first, second) {
    return (first < second) ? first : second;
}

function merge(overlap, newOne) {
    for (let index = 0; index < overlap.length; index++) {
        let res = union(overlap[index], newOne);
        if (res) {
            overlap[index] = res;
            return;
        }
    }
    overlap.push(newOne);
}

function intersect(first, second) {
    if ((first.start > second.end) || (second.start > first.end)) {
        return null;
    }
    return {start: max(first.start, second.start), end: min(first.end, second.end)}
}

function union(first, second) {
    if ((first.start > second.end) || (second.start > first.end)) {
        return null;
    }
    return {start: min(first.start, second.start), end: max(first.end, second.end)}
}

function getOverlaps(persons) {
    let overlaps = persons[0].range;
    for (let i = 1; i < persons.length; i++) {
        let newOverlaps = [];
        for (let o of overlaps) {
            for (let o2 of persons[i].range) {
                let intersection = intersect(o, o2);
                if (intersection) {
                    merge(newOverlaps, intersection);
                }
            }
        }
        if (newOverlaps.length === 0) return [];
        overlaps = newOverlaps;
    }
    return overlaps;
}

const input = [
[
  {
    email: 'test@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '10:00:00', end: '12:00:00' }
    ],
  },
  {
    email: 'elton@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '09:00:00', end: '10:30:00'},
      {start: '10:30:00', end: '11:00:00' }
    ],
  },
  {
    email: 'shawn@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '10:30:00', end: '11:00:00' }
    ],
  },
],
[
  {
    email: 'test@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '10:00:00', end: '12:00:00' }
    ],
  },
  {
    email: 'elton@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '09:00:00', end: '10:30:00'},
      {start: '10:30:00', end: '11:00:00' },
      {start: '14:30:00', end: '15:00:00' }
    ],
  }
],
 [ 
   {
     email: 'test@test.com',
     range: [
       {start: '10:00:00', end: '12:00:00' },
       {start: '14:30:00', end: '15:00:00' }
     ],
   },
   {
     email: 'elton@test.com',
     range: [
       {start: '09:00:00', end: '10:30:00'},
       {start: '10:30:00', end: '11:00:00' },
       {start: '14:30:00', end: '15:00:00' }
     ],
   }
 ]
];

console.log(getOverlaps(input[0]));
console.log(getOverlaps(input[1]));
console.log(getOverlaps(input[2]));
```

Comment: This is very close answer but just missing one thing when you have multiple overlap slot between person slot then it does not output expected. I added the third input example in the main post.

Comment: @Indraraj26 Can you add a comment where you specify inside the comment what value you have and what value you expected?

Comment: I added that third input example in the main post. 

Input: 
```
const input = [
  {
    email: 'test@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '10:00:00', end: '12:00:00' },
      {start: '14:30:00', end: '15:00:00' }
    ],
  },
  {
    email: 'elton@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '09:00:00', end: '10:30:00'},
      {start: '10:30:00', end: '11:00:00' },
      {start: '14:30:00', end: '15:00:00' }
    ],
  }
];

```

I am expecting output 

```
[
 {start: '10:00:00', end: '11:00:00' },
 {start: '14:30:00', end: '15:00:00' }
]
```

Comment: @Indraraj26 you are right, thanks for pointing that out. We needed a validation to be added to the start of the unioning logic. Please look into the edited answer and let me know if it is solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCommonSlots(inp){
    //last time to start will be start time for common slot
    const cStart = Math.max(...inp.map(e => e.range.map(el => new Date(`2024-01-01T${el.start}`).getTime())).flat(2));

    //first time to end will be end time for common slot
    const cEnd = Math.min(...inp.map(e => e.range.map(el => new Date(`2024-01-01T${el.end}`).getTime())).flat(2));

    return [{start: new Date(cStart).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false }),end: new Date(cEnd).toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false })}]
}
```

try this one

Comment: This getting failed for second input example. You can trying with second input example given in the main post.

Comment: Also there can be more slot in the range which will not be common hence we can not use min and max.

Answer (score 0):

Find a common ranges for the two first interviewers, than compare them to the ranges of the next interviewer and repeat to the last interviewer:

```js
function generateIntersectSlot(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) {
    return [];
  }
  let prev = arr[0].range; // take the first interviewer's ranges as the first common ranges
  for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    const curr = []; // collect the common ranges in an array
    for(const p of arr[i].range){
      for(const c of prev){
        if(c.start >= p.start && c.end <= p.end){ // current range is included in the previous, add it
          curr.push(c);
        }else if(p.start >= c.start && p.end <= c.end){ // previous range is included in the current, add it
          curr.push(p);
        }
      }
    }
    if(!curr.length) return [];
    prev = curr; // remember the current common ranges for the next comparison
  }
  
  return prev;
  
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(generateIntersectSlot(input)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(generateIntersectSlot(input2)));
```

```html
<script>
  const input = [{
      email: 'test@test.com',
      range: [{
        start: '10:00:00',
        end: '12:00:00'
      }],
    },
    {
      email: 'elton@test.com',
      range: [{
          start: '09:00:00',
          end: '10:30:00'
        },
        {
          start: '10:30:00',
          end: '11:00:00'
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      email: 'shawn@test.com',
      range: [{
        start: '10:30:00',
        end: '11:00:00'
      }],
    },
  ];
const input2 = [
  {
    email: 'test@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '10:00:00', end: '12:00:00' }
    ],
  },
  {
    email: 'elton@test.com',
    range: [
      {start: '09:00:00', end: '10:30:00'},
      {start: '10:30:00', end: '11:00:00' },
      {start: '14:30:00', end: '15:00:00' }
    ],
  }
];
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try with second input example